# table data is not retrieving in python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am learning selenium. I was trying to collect all image links from vimeo. it logs in successfully and also reach to the portion where's data I want to retrieve. But it is retrieving only first 71 link.I am not understanding where I am going wrong. I also tried to wait for the page load.but still getting only 3 links. also I tried to scroll but nothing changed. what should I do?

```
<table class="sc-jVODtj hxSYTz">
<tbody>

    <tr class="video_manager__table_item" draggable="true">
        <td class="video_manager__table_cell video_manager__checkbox">
            <div class="_16rrx">
                <div class="sc-jhAzac jfCOJP">
                    <label class="_1jZ-U UkGA_ sc-dVhcbM gECuNC sc-jWBwVP iqHKee" format="dark"><span><input type="checkbox" class="sc-fMiknA gpqhYy" value="on"><span class="sc-fBuWsC dGFkNH"><div class="sc-fAjcbJ kvdeNU"></div></span><span class="sc-eqIVtm jIEUZS"></span></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <!-- react-empty: 578 -->
                    <!-- react-empty: 579 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="video_manager__table_cell video_manager__table_cell--thumb">
            <div class="table_cell__thumb-wrapper" data-fatal-attraction="container:video_manager_list|component:video|keyword:thumbnail">
                <a target="_blank" href="/321669493/settings">
                    <div class="_1tULj">
                        <div class="_3XET0" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/764433135_236x133.jpg&quot;);"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="video_manager__table_item" draggable="true">
        <td class="video_manager__table_cell video_manager__checkbox">
            <div class="_16rrx">
                <div class="sc-jhAzac jfCOJP">
                    <label class="_1jZ-U UkGA_ sc-dVhcbM gECuNC sc-jWBwVP iqHKee" format="dark"><span><input type="checkbox" class="sc-fMiknA gpqhYy" value="on"><span class="sc-fBuWsC dGFkNH"><div class="sc-fAjcbJ kvdeNU"></div></span><span class="sc-eqIVtm jIEUZS"></span></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <!-- react-empty: 602 -->
                    <!-- react-empty: 603 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="video_manager__table_cell video_manager__table_cell--thumb">
            <div class="table_cell__thumb-wrapper" data-fatal-attraction="container:video_manager_list|component:video|keyword:thumbnail">
                <a target="_blank" href="/319499775/settings">
                    <div class="_1tULj">
                        <div class="_3XET0" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/762092910_236x133.jpg&quot;);"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="video_manager__table_item" draggable="true">
        <td class="video_manager__table_cell video_manager__checkbox">
            <div class="_16rrx">
                <div class="sc-jhAzac jfCOJP">
                    <label class="_1jZ-U UkGA_ sc-dVhcbM gECuNC sc-jWBwVP iqHKee" format="dark"><span><input type="checkbox" class="sc-fMiknA gpqhYy" value="on"><span class="sc-fBuWsC dGFkNH"><div class="sc-fAjcbJ kvdeNU"></div></span><span class="sc-eqIVtm jIEUZS"></span></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <!-- react-empty: 626 -->
                    <!-- react-empty: 627 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="video_manager__table_cell video_manager__table_cell--thumb">
            <div class="table_cell__thumb-wrapper" data-fatal-attraction="container:video_manager_list|component:video|keyword:thumbnail">
                <a target="_blank" href="/319303335/settings">
                    <div class="_1tULj">
                        <div class="_3XET0" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/761962359_236x133.jpg&quot;);"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

code

```
 from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, \
WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/lmuser/chromedriver')
driver.get ("https://vimeo.com/log_in")
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_email").send_keys("**")
driver.find_element_by_id("login_password").send_keys("**")
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Log in with 
email']")
login.click()
all_video = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/manage/videos']//span//span[@class='_3jCKf -kEHD sc-jWBwVP iqHKee']//span[@class='_2i129']")
all_video.click()

x=1

time.sleep(3)
for i in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr'):
   path = "//tr["+str(x)+"]//td[2]//div[1]//a[1]//div[1]//div[1]"
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path))
    )
   print(element.get_attribute("style"))
   print(x)
   x=x+1
   time.sleep(1)
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Comment: I guess this line is the issue `for i in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'table'):`, It will run your loop based on how many tables you have in your webpage. Instead you want to check how many rows are in the specific table and run your loop based on that value.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I changed the element by <td> but it goes until 71 and stops again!

Comment: Please edit your question and update with what you tried. Also if there are 3 tables on the webpage then you should get the number of <tr>(because you are looking for one link in every tr element) elements in just that table(using xpath) and run your loop that many times.

Comment: Thank you. I could solve it :)